# White border on Microsoft Outlook 2016

Tags: html, css, html-email

Almost every browser Mail Clients looks fine, but a little bit white border after learn more text on Microsoft outlook 2016 !

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Example Code

```html
<table class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:18px;padding-left:18px;" class="mcnButtonBlockInner" valign="top" align="left">
        <table class="mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-collapse:separate !important;border:2px none #9E8B5B;border-radius:0px;background-color:#54534A;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;font-size:13px;padding:13px;" valign="middle" align="center">
                <a class="mcnButton" title="LEARN MORE" href="https://www.ihg.com/intercontinental/hotels/gb/en/dhaka/dachb/hoteldetail/meetings-events#scmisc=nav_meetings-events_ic" target="_blank" style="font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:100%;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:#CBC5BE;">LEARN MORE</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't undertand please provide us more informations, what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `tr`:

```
<tr style="background-color:#54534A;">
```